# I want to select which audio input the Android uses for Bluetooth microphone instead of phones mic

Tags: select, audio, input, bluetooth

Is it possible for unrooted phone to be able to select the audio input used? I would like to be able to select the Bluetooth microphone input to substitute the standard microphone on the phone. So that all times, more than just the calls, audio input could be handled through the Bluetooth headset.